# How do I remove duplicates from two different lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates

What I want to do is to remove duplicate words which appear in `positive` and `negative`. This is the code which I used.

```
positive= 'an excellent film'
negative='a bad film'

for i in [positive]:
    if i in [negative]:
        print (i)
        positive.remove(i)
    print (positive)
```

However, this code will print all the positive words instead of positive words without the duplicates. How can I change the code?

Desired output:

```
positive= 'an', 'excellent'
negative= 'a', 'bad'
```

Comment: Post a desired input output please.  See [mcve]

Comment: @user3483203 done

Comment: Why are `a` and `an` removed, they are not duplicates

Comment: list(set(list1).intersection(list2))

Comment: Is order of your outputs important?

Answer (score 2):

Using Amit Parashar's hint:

```
positive = 'an excellent film'
negative = 'a bad film'

positive = set(positive.split())
negative = set(negative.split())

positive_uniq = positive.difference(negative)
negative_uniq = negative.difference(positive)

print(positive)  # {'an', 'excellent'}
print(negative)  # {'a', 'bad'}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `intersection` and `difference_update`. Just use `difference` for both strings

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, it is pretty easy to do by using **"SET"** data structure of Python. However, if you want to do it by using only lists, you can refer the below solution.

We need to **split** the **strings** so that Python can consider it as different words and then using **two nested for loops**, the work is done. Lasty, I'm using join method to print it the way you explained in *Desired Output*.

```
positive = 'an excellent film'
negative = 'a bad film'

positive = positive.split()
negative = negative.split()

for i in positive:
    if i in negative:
      positive.remove(i)
      negative.remove(i)

for j in negative:
    if j in positive:
      negative.remove(j)
      positive.remove(j)

print("Positive:", ", ".join(positive))
print("Negative:", ", ".join(negative))
```